# How to query Json objects using linq.js?

Tags: javascript, json, linq.js

I'm converting a xml file to a Json format, I'm trying to query the Json using [linq.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/linq)
so far this is what I've done:

```
var queryResult  = linq.from(result).where( function(x){ return x.key == "bpmn2:definitions"   } ).select(function(x)  {  return x } ).toArray();
```

and I get the following json:

```
[ { key: 'bpmn2:definitions',
    value:
     { '$': [Object],
       'bpmn2:message': [Object],
       'bpmn2:interface': [Object],
       process: [Object] } } ]
```

how can I get in the same query just by modifying the where clause  the embedded object named **Process**?

**EDIT:**

I've made it so far:

```
var queryResult  = linq.from(result).where( function(x){ return x.key == "bpmn2:definitions"   } ).select(function(x)  {  return x.value.process } ).toArray();
```

and I get

```
[ [ { '$': [Object],
      'bpmn2:process': [Object],
      'bpmndi:BPMNDiagram': [Object] } ] ]
```

how can I access bpmn2:process within the same query described above?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? I think this is what you're asking.

```
var queryResult  = linq.from(result).where( function(x){ return x.key == "bpmn2:definitions"   } ).select(function(x)  {  return x.value.process } ).toArray();
```

Comment: thanks Joe, I just got into the same result a minute ago, thanks for the answer that's correct if you can take a look I edited the question I'm trying to elaborate a more complex query, sorry for the edit

Comment: I did it this way I feels a little bit dirty to me:  linq.from(result).where( function(x){ return x.key == "bpmn2:definitions"   } ).select(function(x)  {  return x.value.process[0]["bpmn2:process"] } ).toArray(); anyway it works! thanks for the help

Comment: @Pedro just as a sidenote. I would not use x.key == "bpmn2:definitions" because for every comparison you do a typecast. Use the strict equality comparer "===" not "==". The "==" is only good to use when you compare an integer like 2 and yo do not care wether 2 is also a "2". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons